# Remove "-" in all cell datas in Excel?

Tags: excel, ms-office, vba

> I have 700 datas on one column in Excel and this datas has
>   "0956-989-52" format. How I can convert these datas to new format
>   "095698252", I means whitout "-" notation?

Comment: `=MID(A1,1,4)&MID(A1,6,3)&MID(A1,10,2)` ?  Or `=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","")` ?

Comment: You means wrote it in all cells, @YowE3K

Comment: Yes.  It depends on whether it is a one-off task, or whether you need to do it every time new data is placed in the cells though.

Comment: I means how I can apply it to one column that has datas? @YowE3K

Comment: With all due respect, but this is a site for programming. If you don't know how to do the most basic things in Excel, go to Superuser.com

Comment: If it is a one-off, follow teylyn's solution.  If it needs to happen automatically, just insert an extra column with the formula to convert it in each cell in the new column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the column and set its format to text. This will prevent the converted data from being interpreted as numbers and lose leading zeros,

Use Find and Replace (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd>). In "Find what" enter a - sign. Leave "Replace with" blank and hit <kbd>Replace All</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

If the data converts to General or Number and you lose the leading zeros then you might want to use:

```
=TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",""),"000000000")
```